# VSC hide menu bar on wheel click

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently the menu hides when you click crtl + b, and I would like the menu to hide when you click wheel in the mouse, is it possible to do this somehow?

Comment: when clicking the mouse wheel _where_ in the UI? anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible without an external program at the current VS code. Mouse buttons cannot be used in shortcuts. Refer to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/43794 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3130.

Alternatively, you can use external programs (AutoHotkey in Windows, BetterTouchTool in Mac like in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/43794#issuecomment-614574567) to map the wheel click to a rarely used Keyboard key or key combination and do the following in VS code.

1. Press Ctrl + Shift + P
2. Type `Shortcut`
3. Select `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts"
4. Type `Ctrl+B`
5. Change the shortcut of Ctrl+B to your customized key or key combination.